# Using multiple axios get requests inside useEffect yields undefined values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I'm very new to React and web development as a whole, and I know the code is styled terribly but bear with me please.

I'm attempting to get weather data with openweathermap API, which I have to use latitude and longitude for my desired location, which I am supposed to get from their separate geocoding API when I feed it the capital and country code of a country I'm interested in.

I'm kind of unsure how to "stack" these requests so that the first coordinate request goes through and gives the coordinates to the second, weather request. My problem, is that the coordinates (which I otherwise get successfully) are given as undefined to my next request, and I can't figure out why, and I've tried a lot.

```
const Content = ({result}) => {
  const languages = [result['languages']]
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([])
  const [coordinate, setCoordinates] = useState([])
  const api_key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${result['capital']},${result['cca2']}&limit=1&appid=${api_key}`)
        .then(response => {
          setCoordinates(response.data)
        })
        .then(() =>
            axios
                .get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/onecall?lat=${coordinate['lat']}&lon=${coordinate['lon']}&exclude=1&appid=${api_key}`)
                .then(response => {
                  setWeather(response.data)
            }))
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

`setCoordinates` does not update `coordinate` immediately, as React batches state updates. States are therefore updated asynchronously.

If your second request is dependent on state changes to the `coordinate` array, then you should move it into its own `useEffect` hook:

```
const Content = ({result}) => {
  const languages = [result['languages']]
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([])
  const [coordinate, setCoordinates] = useState([])
  const api_key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${result['capital']},${result['cca2']}&limit=1&appid=${api_key}`)
        .then(response => {
            setCoordinates(response.data)
        });
  }, []);

  // Your second API call is dependent on state changes to `coordinate`
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/onecall?lat=${coordinate['lat']}&lon=${coordinate['lon']}&exclude=1&appid=${api_key}`)
        .then(response => {
            setWeather(response.data)
        });
  }, [coordinate]);
};
```

Comment: coordinate array still passes as undefined to the weather request, I think the coordinate request just doesn't get processed fast enough to give the weather request the coordinates, so I still don't know how to fix that

Comment: @Dharmapala You probably need to check if `coordinates` is an empty array or object. It’s not clear in your question what is the expected type. You initialize it as an array but access it like an object. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
const Content = ({result}) => {
  const languages = [result['languages']]
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([])
  const [coordinate, setCoordinates] = useState([])
  const api_key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY

  useEffect(() => {
    let coordinateResult = [];
    axios
        .get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${result['capital']},${result['cca2']}&limit=1&appid=${api_key}`)
        .then(response => {
          coordinateResult = response.data;
        })
        .then(() =>
            axios
                .get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/onecall?lat=${coordinateResult['lat']}&lon=${coordinateResult['lon']}&exclude=1&appid=${api_key}`)
                .then(response => {
                  setCoordinates(coordinateResult);
                  setWeather(response.data)
            }))
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])
```

Focus that `setState` function is asynchronous.